# Do MySQL transaction logs grow out of hand?

Tags: mysql, transaction-log

I used to manage Microsoft SQL Server installations. Now I'm up against a **MySQL 5.1** server.

On MSSQL, I remember databases have transaction log files which grow larger and larger as transactions occur. If you don't **truncate the files** every now and then, you will eventually run out of disk space. So even if you compact your databases by deleting old rows, disk space will be running out.

I wonder if MySQL behaves similarly and what steps I need to take to make sure that disk space won't get depleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same is true with MySQL (and any database server with logging) when you have binary logging enabled.

Check out the [MySQL documentation regarding binary logging](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log.html&ei=u55lUPKAE6bs2gXnzYDQBQ&usg=AFQjCNEQhMfS_5kyjgquas3J5t_HmMEGuQ&sig2=S79jyNFAQGMIMxDfYRxaYw) as it points out a number of variables that effect the size of the logs and how often they get rotated.

In addition the section on [Log Maintenance](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/log-file-maintenance.html) will also be important to you.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if binary logging is enabled by default? [The docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html) appear to say all logging is off.

Comment: I have found that whether binary logging is enabled by default is dependent upon every installation. If you have access to the mysql configuration file (usually /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf) you can grep for log-bin for it's value.

Comment: If you don't have access to the configuration file you could issue the command SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin'; in the mysql client.